# set irc server password

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, irc, ubuntu-11.04

I just recently set up an IRC server on my Ubuntu box (11.04, no remix), and would like to set up a server password that one must provide on login. How do I do this?

I have `dancer-ircd` and `dancer-services` installed if it makes any difference

Comment: Hey, I am not stalking you. Just seen your question on serverfault was migrated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your IRC private so everyone must specify a password to use the server.
This question has been answered on serverfault.com in the past.

Check out https://serverfault.com/questions/89466/how-can-i-configure-a-private-friends-only-irc-server

Comment: so would `I:*:<pass>:*` work for this?

Comment: ya know, since we're on the topic of IRC, how do I make it so that IRC admins/operators can `chanop` themselves?